# How do I deserialize a JSON array(flat) and ignore some token

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have this response  from server

```
 [{
  "sys_id": "******************************",
  "dv_model_id": "*****************",
  "due": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
  "assigned_to": "1524s32a54dss412s121s",
  "dv_assigned_to": "username",
  "assigned_to.phone": "+12345678910",
  "assigned_to.email": "abc@a.c",
  "u_borrower_id": "fb36e45f0a12452004742183457e833b0",
  "dv_u_borrower_id": "antoherUserName",
  "u_borrower_id.phone": "+12345678910",
  "u_borrower_id.email": "abcf@a.c"
}
,{....}
,{....}]
```

I'm trying to deserialize this to List

```
public class Inventory
{
    public Inventory()
    {
        assigned_to = new User();
        u_borrower_wwid = new User();
    }

    public string sys_ID { get; set; }
    public string dv_model_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime due { get; set; }
    public string dv_assigned_to { get; set; }
    public User assigned_to { get; set; }
    public string dv_u_borrower_id { get; set; }
    public User u_borrower_id { get; set; }
}
```

now, since the JSON contains -  "assigned_to": "1524s32a54dss412s121s"," 
the deserialization failed. 
the same with the - ""u_borrower_id": "fb36e45f0a12452004742183457e833b0"," .

do you know any way to ignore them? or remove them from the JSON? 
I need only the properties (".phone" and ".email") of the object.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of solutions:

---

**Modify your `Inventory` object (or create a new one)** so the json can be fully deserialized, then access the values there.

Your new and updated object should look like this:

```
public class InventoryJsonObject
{
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
    public string dv_model_id { get; set; }
    public string due { get; set; }
    public string assigned_to { get; set; }
    public string dv_assigned_to { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("assigned_to.phone")]
    public string assigned_to_phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("assigned_to.email")]
    public string assigned_to_email { get; set; }
    public string u_borrower_id { get; set; }
    public string dv_u_borrower_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("u_borrower_id.phone")]
    public string u_borrower_id_phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("u_borrower_id.email")]
    public string u_borrower_id_email { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Use regular expressions to get the values from the string.** In this case your regex would be `"u_borrower_id\.phone": "(.*?)"` and `"u_borrower_id\.email": "(.*?)"`

The complete regex solution could look like this (assuming every object has a phone and email included):

```
string phonePattern = "\"u_borrower_id\\.phone\": \"(.*?)\"";
string emailPattern = "\"u_borrower_id\\.email\": \"(.*?)\"";

Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(phonePattern);
var phoneMatches = phoneRegex.Matches(input);

Regex emailRegex = new Regex(emailPattern);
var emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(input);

for (int i = 0; i < phoneMatches.Count; i++)
{
    string phoneMatch = phoneMatches[i].Groups[1].Value;
    string emailMatch = emailMatches[i].Groups[1].Value;
    // Now you can add them to any collection you desire
}
```

---

**Implement a cast between `string` and `User`.** Since your error originates from the fact that the string `fb36e45f0a12452004742183457e833b0` cannot be cast into a `User` object trivially, you have to implement the cast. It would look like this:

```
public static implicit operator User(string _string)
{
    // This could be a DB lookup, or basically anything else
    return new User()
    {
        id = _string
    };
}
```

Comment: ok, but how should I ignore the flat information? (u_borrower_id) it's throw an exception
`Could not cast or convert from System.String to Models.User.`
`Error converting value "755231490a12165100163a8b96a688b9" to type 'Models.User'. Path '[0].assigned_to', line 1, position 536.`

Comment: Create a new model called where `u_borrower_id` and `assigned_to` are strings, not `User`s.

Comment: @danielziv You are getting the error because the serializer is trying to convert the string "username" and "fb36e45f0a12452004742183457e833b0" into an object of type `User`.

Comment: so basically I need to flat the object either then parse it back to the inventory object?

Comment: @danielziv Yeah, that is one solution, you could also implement a cast between string and User (this might be the cleanest). Check out the edit I just made.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid unnecessary casting that causes bug you can use this workaround by creating a `Dictionary<string, object>`
 **and read only the properties you need** as strings and convert them to your desired type:

```
using System.Web.Script;

Dictionary<string, object> dict = Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Now you can modify your class properties one by one like:
(You can create additional method for your DateTime and User property)

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

//notice i'v added the 'u_borrower_id_email' property to your class:
inventory.u_borrower_id_email = dict.GetStringOrDefault("u_borrower_id.phone");

private static string GetStringOrDefault(this Dictionary<string, object> data, string key)
{
    string result = "";
    object o;
    if (data.TryGetValue(key, out o))
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            result = o.ToString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```